# magento 2 upgrade to 2.1.3

Tags: magento, upgrade, magento2

After I upgrade a Magento 2.0.11 to 2.1.3 i got an error. I searched internet but cannot found a solution.

Commands I did on terminal from magento root folder:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.3 --no-update
./composer.json has been updated
composer update
rm -rf var/di var/generation
chmod -R 777 var/ pub/
rm -rf var/di var/generation
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

ERROR:

> [Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException]   Requested
>   store is not found

ERROR ON FRONT:

> Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException: Requested store is
>   not found in
>   /home/discusshop/sites/discusshop.nl/www/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreRepository.php:111
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/discusshop/sites/discusshop.nl/www/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreManager.php(164):
>   Magento\Store\Model\StoreRepository->getById('2') #1
>   /home/discusshop/sites/discusshop.nl/www/var/generation/Magento/Store/Model/StoreManagerInterface/Proxy.php(119):
>   Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager->getStore('2') #2
>   /home/discusshop/sites/discusshop.nl/www/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Resolver/Store.php(29):
>   Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface\Proxy->getStore('2') #3
>   /home/discusshop/sites/discusshop.nl/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/ScopeCodeResolver.php(49):
>   Magento\Store\Model\Resolver\Store->getScope('2') #4
>   /home/discusshop/sites/discusshop.nl/www/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Source/RuntimeConfigSource.php(82):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeCodeResolver->resolve('stores', '2')
>   5 /home/discusshop/sites/discusshop.nl/www/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Source/RuntimeConfigSource.php(58):
>   Magento\Config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->loadConfig() #6
>   /home/discusshop/sites/discusshop.nl/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/ConfigSourceAggregated.php(40):
>   Magento\Config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->get('') #7
>   /home/discusshop/sites/discusshop.nl/www/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/Config/ConfigSourceAggregated/Proxy.php(95):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated->get('') #8
>   /home/discusshop/sites/discusshop.nl/www/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(98):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated\Proxy->get() #9
>   /home/discusshop/sites/discusshop.nl/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(139):
>   Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->get('default/web/sec...') #10
>   /home/discusshop/sites/discusshop.nl/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(90):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Config->get('system', 'default/web/sec...') #11
>   /home/discusshop/sites/discusshop.nl/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(103):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('web/secure/use_...',
>   'default', NULL) #12
>   /home/discusshop/sites/discusshop.nl/www/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/HeaderProvider/Hsts.php(48):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Config->isSetFlag('web/secure/use_...') #13
>   /home/discusshop/sites/discusshop.nl/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Response/HeaderManager.php(41):
>   Magento\Store\Model\HeaderProvider\Hsts->canApply() #14
>   /home/discusshop/sites/discusshop.nl/www/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(123):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Response\HeaderManager->beforeSendResponse(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
>   15 /home/discusshop/sites/discusshop.nl/www/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/Response/Http/Interceptor.php(117):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('sendResponse',
>   Array, Array) #16
>   /home/discusshop/sites/discusshop.nl/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(185):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->sendResponse() #17
>   /home/discusshop/sites/discusshop.nl/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(156):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->handleDeveloperMode(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException)) #18
>   /home/discusshop/sites/discusshop.nl/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(263):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->catchException(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException)) #19
>   /home/discusshop/sites/discusshop.nl/www/pub/index.php(37):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
>   20 {main}

Answer (score 1):

Magento\Store\Model\StoreRepository->getById('2')

You need to look at the way you created and deleted some of the stores.

Looks like a stire with store ID 2 was created and later removed but for some reason some traces left so that upgrade code is searching for this store.

Suggestion : Look at DB and try to locate where store ID 2 entry exist and remove( Be careful when doing something directly on DB).